# The type org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver is not accessible

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I need help in setting up selenium in MAC OS.
I have added all the required selenium jar files and java JRE to build path.
I have added java path in .profile
But still I am still getting error for Firefox driver.

```
The type org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver is not accessible
```

Can you please help.

[image: Screenshot of the Error]

Comment: "I have added all the required selenium jar files" - ? Where you got them? Your version of selenium-firefox-driver jar does not match the version of selenium-server-standalone jar.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Go through the below links (if not gone through already) which have the guide lines on when and how to ask a question on the forum.[Help Center>>Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The error that you are getting could be for multiple reason. 1. Restart your eclipse 2.Try to remove and again add the jar files to the project.

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
The type org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver is not accessible
```

...implies that the **GeckoDriver** was not accessible by your program/script,

Your main issue is the presence of numerous unwanted **JAR** files containing the same class which are:

- *selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar*
- *Selenium-Java* client JARs.
- *selenium-firefox-driver-2.35.0.jar*

### Solution

- Remove all the JARs and add back only ***selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar***
- Download the required format of **GeckoDriver** executable from [mozilla/geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases), extract the binary and then initialize the FirefoxDriveras follows:

  ```
  //imports
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

  //other lines of code
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\path\\to\\geckodriver.exe");
  driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
  ```

Comment: Hi,I have removed all jar files and added back selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar and added System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/Users/name/Downloads/geckodriver"); But still im getting same error.

Comment: Clean the project workspace through the IDE menu. Build the project again. Run your tests.

Comment: Hi, I did clean and build project. The error near import FirefoxDriver is not going away. But able to launch the firefox. Console Error:-1541364135412 mozrunner:"/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin" "-marionette" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/var/folders/cw/xtcb87756jnfy46wbl380df80000gp/T/rust_mozprofile.JqtVHDhmVETv"
1541364137030 Marionette INFO Listening on port 52242
1541364137060 MarionetteWARN TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session Nov 04, 2018 12:42:17 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession INFO: Detected dialect: W3C

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue,

1. create a new Java project with JRE syetm libraray (JavaSE  1.8)
2. copy jar file and build path
3. copy driver executables

Create new class and move on with your work!!!

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in your 'Referenced Libraries' folder, you seem to have added both the selenium-standalone-3.x.x.jar and the individual client-combined-3.x.x versions of the jar files (selenium client jars for java). Is it possible that your eclipse does not know which libraries to finally use? Request you to remove all the libraries in your build path and add ONLY the selenium-server-standalone-3.x.x.jar file. Once done, refresh and this should resolve.

Also, once the right jars are in place, the import should resolve even without the System.setProperty instruction in your class file.

If the issue persists, could you please paste a screen capture without the right-click context menu on the error?
Hope this helps.

Comment: Most of this answer should be a comment. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead

Answer (score 0):

The pretty simple solution is " You might have created module while creating the package. So simply delete the module it will resolve the issue. It worked for me!!